# What is meant by "AWT widgets written in Java which delegated to peer classes that were written in C"?

Tags: java, c, swing, java-native-interface, native

I don't understand the meaning of

> The original Java AWT was implemented by having widgets written in Java which delegated to peer classes that were written in C

The *"peer classes that were written in C"* part:

It means Java classes included native code?

Comment: peer classes that were written in C...It mean Java classes included native code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hotspot Java has substantial parts of the runtime system written in C / C++.  At one point, this included the AWT peer classes.  (And it still may do ... )

The native code is not "in" the Java.  Rather, the Java typically has `native` method declarations that typically get bound to a native implementation when the corresponding native library is loaded.

(But don't take this as a green light do the same thing in your code.  Interfacing with native code is tricky, and if you get it wrong you are liable to trigger hard JVM crashes ... and a world of pain ...)

Comment: +1 Yes, all Swing [*Top-Level Containers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) dwell in host peer components.

Answer (score 1):

I understood now. The AWT toolkit used native components by using C code in peer classeswhich is solved in Swing. Thank u @Andrew